# Pycharm 'No module named rospy'

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pycharm IDE doesn't seem to recognize ROS modules (It underlines them and doesn't autocomplete), even though when I run the script, the interpreter does recognize them.
I should add that I am opening pycharm from a linux terminal, after I have sourced the ROS environment (/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash) and the local catkin worksapce.
How can I solve the problem?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406569/pycharm-%27no-module-named-rospy%27/) by [amit_z](https://answers.ros.org/users/56857/amit_z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2022-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-18**:
this may help: https://youtu.be/lTew9mbXrAs

**Comment by [amit_z](https://answers.ros.org/users/56857/amit_z/) on 2022-09-20**:
Thanks! it was helpful indeed

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-20**:
glad you made it work.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-09-20**:
Please add a text solution as an answer, videos and websites may be taken down later, future readers then will not benefit from your help now

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will also work to start pycharm from a terminal where ROS is already sourced

---

Originally posted by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) with karma: 183 on 2022-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was presented here by ravijoshi:
https://youtu.be/lTew9mbXrAs

(adding the ros python3/dist-packages library as a content root in the Project Structure)

---

Originally posted by [amit_z](https://answers.ros.org/users/56857/amit_z/) with karma: 51 on 2022-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1